# How do I display matrix fields inside of a relationship field (channel entry)?

Tags: channel-entries, matrix, relationships, multiple-channels

Anybody have an answer? I am trying to do this in EE 2.6, but the matrix fields don't display. I have a channel (fruit) with a relationship field to another channel. That channel (kinds) has a matrix field called locations. Inside of locations is a column called state. I'm trying to get a list of states to display.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="fruit" limit="1"}

{related-entry-kinds} <-- name of field inside of fruit channel

{related-entry-kinds:title} <-- this displays fine

{related-entry-kinds:locations} <--name of matrix field

{related-entry-kinds:locations:state} <--doesn't render

{/related-entry-kinds:locations}

{/related-entry-kinds}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

Matrix doesn't do the inheritance like that. Just simply used the fields as you would a regular matrix field

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="fruit" limit="1"}

   {related-entry-kinds} <-- name of field inside of fruit channel

      {related-entry-kinds:title} <-- this displays fine

      {related-entry-kinds:locations} <--name of matrix field

         {state}

      {/related-entry-kinds:locations}

   {/related-entry-kinds}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If you are paranoid, you can use the var_prefix parameter (check it out on [here](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/templating/field.html)). They do something similar but with playa. It should work the same for relationships